# how to show two to one relationship in google org chart in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

```
<script src="orgchart/orgchart.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ["orgchart"]
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  var lst = [];

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip'); // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show. data.addRows([ [{ v: 'ScanImport002', f: 'Scan Import' }, '', ''], [{ v: 'Fusion', f: 'Fusion' }, 'ScanImport002', ''], [{ v: 'DosimetristContouring003', f: 'Dosimetrist Contouring' }, 'ScanImport002', ''], // ['Dosimetrist Contouring', 'ScanImport002', ''], [{ v: 'test003', f: 'test' }, 'DosimetristContouring003', ''], [{ v: 'Physicist Chart Check003 ', f: 'Physicist Chart Check' }, 'test003', ''], [{ v: 'Physicist Chart Check0031 ', f: 'Physicist Chart Check' }, 'Therapist Chart Check012', ''], [{ v: 'Therapist Chart Check012', f: 'Therapist Chart Check' }, 'DosimetristContouring003', ''], // ['Plan Completion2', 'Dosimetrist Contouring', ''], ['Plan Completion', 'Fusion', 'Bob Sponge'], ['MD Check', 'Plan Completion', ''], ['Plan Documentation', 'MD Check', ''], ['Physicist Initial Chart Check', 'Plan Documentation', ''], // ['Therapist Chart Check', 'Physicist Initial Chart Check', ''] ]); console.log(data); var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true }); }
```

Comment: This is my code .i want two to one relationship use google org chart.this code worked one to one ,two to many,many to many but not worked two to one .anybody solve my problem